# Installing 3TB SATA Hard Drive Messed Up My Computer

Tags: windows-7, sata, bsod

I just added a 3TB SATA hard drive to my Windows 7 x64 machine. After formatting it, it seemed to work for a couple of hours until I got a BSOD. 10 minutes later, another BSOD, this one saying memory management issues. Both times after starting back up I had a message saying there was a problem with overclocking, however, I haven't overclocked my machine.

Anyhow, the machine didn't boot up after that, I couldn't even get the post screen for a while. I unplugged the drive and still no post screen, no beeps, nothing. Eventually for no reason it started up, i went into safe mode and did a System Restore. The machine froze when booting back up afterward.

This is where I am now. Trying to boot up again but no luck. Can anyone shed some light on what is going on?

---

**EDIT (from comment):**

I've managed to get into the BIOS, didn't see anything wierd, but I wouldn't really know. Exited without saving to a nice "bootmgr is missing" message. Back into the BIOS and it seems boot order has changed with some stuff missing. Still don't know what is going on.

**EDIT 2:**

So I did a memory test that said I have a hardware issue. Then i tried testing each stick of RAM individually. All passed. Then I tried testing a single stick in each dimm. All passed. Now i'm trying combinations, however don't really understand how a combination wont work when everything works individually. On another note, I guess the hard drive installation and my memory issue must just be coincidental?

Comment: update: Managed to get into the bios, didnt see anything wierd, but i wouldnt really know. Exited without saving to a nice "bootmgr is missing" messge. Back into the bios and it seems boot order has changed with some stuff missing. Still dont know what is going on

Comment: I suspect your BIOS needs an update. If there isn't one available, you may be out of luck. Permanent damage from plugging in a new hard drive is unlikely. Alternatively, you may have run into PSU issues. By adding a new device (though unlikely), you stretched the power supply to its maximum, and *that* can have permanent damage.

Comment: Thanks Randolph, I have a 1kw power unit, so cant imagine that is being stretched.